# Comment makes ng-options work, why?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So, I was working through a bug concerning the `ngOptions` directive within an `ngInclude`.  I came across sample code showing the directive working, copy-pasted it in, and saw that both my (non-functioning) old `ngOptions` was now functioning.  I'm curious as to how that worked.

I no longer have access to the old code, but it looked something like this:

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="Widget" ng-class="{{widget.properties.styleClass}}" ng-init="optionsShow = false" class="irrelevant" "style = "height:100%;" >
    <div>
        <!-- ... -->

        <!-- my options button-->
        <span class="icon" ng-click="showOptions(); adjustHeight()">
           options
        </span>
    </div>

<!-- Options div shows only when button is clicked -->
<!-- Canvas Options -->
<div class="options command-options" ng-show="optionsShow" style="height:50%;">
    <!-- ... -->
    <span ng-click="addCommand()">Add New Command +</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label>Command to edit:<br/>
                <select  ng-model="selected" ng-change="verifySelected()" ng-options="object as object.index for object in widget.objects"></select>
                <!-- The select here wouldn't show any options no matter what I did -->
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

JS, within the controller:

```
//...
$scope.widget.objects = [];
//...
$scope.addObject = function(){
    $scope.widget.objects.push({index:$scope.widget.objects.length + 1, type:$scope.objectTypes[0]});
}
$scope.addObject();
$scope.verifySelected = function(){
 console.log("irrelevant")
}
```

The working HTML now looks like this:

```
<div ng-controller="Widget" ng-class="{{widget.properties.styleClass}}" ng-init="optionsShow = false" class="irrelevant" "style = "height:100%;" >
    <div>
        <!-- ... -->
        <!--  The following comments help make thing work in the options div.  Don't ask why, I don't know.  Just don't remove them

               <b>Total Things:</b> {{totalThings}}
             <p ng-repeat="oneThing in things">
                <input value="{{oneThing.text}}" type="checkbox" ng-model="oneThing.checked" />
                {{oneThing.text}}
                </p>
              <ul class="unstyled">
              <li ng-repeat="oneThing in things">
                    <span>{{oneThing.text}}</span>
        </li></ul>-->
        <!-- my options button, everything below this point unchanged-->
        <span class="icon" ng-click="showOptions(); adjustHeight()">
            options
        </span>
    </div>

<!-- Options div shows only when button is clicked -->
<!-- Canvas Options -->
<div class="options command-options" ng-show="optionsShow" style="height:50%;">
    <!-- ... -->
    <span ng-click="addCommand()">Add New Command +</span>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-xs-3">
            <label>Command to edit:<br/>
                <select  ng-model="selected" ng-change="verifySelected()" ng-options="object as object.index for object in widget.objects"></select>
                <!-- The select here wouldn't show any options no matter what I did -->
            </label>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<!-- ... -->
```

The working JS controller now also has these lines:

```
$scope.totalThings = 5;
//...
$scope.things = [{text: 'This is needed in order to make things work... for some reason.'}];
```

What happened to make it work?

Comment: Make a [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) of it, which shows the problem. We can't really work off "I'm not sure, but I think it looked something like this."

Comment: These might help - [ngOptions Attribute](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngOptions) and [A brief walk-through](http://www.undefinednull.com/2014/08/11/a-brief-walk-through-of-the-ng-options-in-angularjs/)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

ngOptions works as expected with your old code, I have made a plunker with your old code [widget plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/VyBVXG7iM7mQCH0TEamC?p=preview)`$scope.widget = {};` and `$scope.objectTypes = ["something"];` are added to make your code working.